# Animate over many different divs in Jquery using step

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I have many divs that I want to rotate at once. I looked online and found a way to do it using the step function. An example of what I want is shown below:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
    var div = document.getElementById(i);
    $(div).animate({ left: 0}, {
    step: function(now) {
        $(div).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
    }
})
```

However, in the for loop i changes, so div changes, so it only rotates the div with id 100. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want to achieve which is animating 100 divs at once, I can say that selecting every div independently is the wrong way, so you can just tag all divs that you want animate at once by a common class and just target that class from JQuery, then animate and you should have the correct behavior that you want.

here is an example:

```js
$('div.anim').animate(
    { deg: 360 },
    {
      duration: 2000,
      step: function(now) {
        $(this).css({ transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)' });
      }
    }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="0" class="anim" style="height:60px;width:60px;border:3px black solid;">text 0</div>
 <div id="1" class="anim" style="height:60px;width:60px;border:3px black solid;">text 1</div>
 <div id="2" class="anim" style="height:60px;width:60px;border:3px black solid;">text 2</div>
 <div id="3" class="anim" style="height:60px;width:60px;border:3px black solid;">text 3</div>
```